# inf-sup condition for the Stokes problem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, fluid-dynamics, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^d$
- $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be bounded, convex, nonempty and open
- $p\in L^2(\Lambda)$ with $$\int_\Lambda p\:{\rm d}\lambda=0\tag1$$

> I want to show that there is a unique $v\in H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$ with $$\nabla\cdot v=p\tag2$$ and $$\left\|v\right\|_{H^1(\Lambda,\:\mathbb R^d)}\le C\left\|p\right\|_{L^2(\Lambda)}\tag3\;.$$

By [Theorem 3.2.1.2](https://books.google.de/books?id=lJTtujsZSgkC&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=%22In+the+following+results%22+%22denotes+the+same+operator+as+in%22&source=bl&ots=GSMySOPKim&sig=beytYwPLi_Jor6-tXxBPgbMzPJM&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8292pxpfSAhXmHpoKHf4FCQcQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22In%20the%20following%20results%22%20%22denotes%20the%20same%20operator%20as%20in%22&f=true) of *Elliptic Problems in Nonsmooth Domains* by *Pierre Grisvard*, there is a unique $u\in H_0^1(\Lambda)\cap H^2(\Lambda)$ with $$\Delta u=p\tag4\;.$$ So, $$v:=\nabla u$$ is a solution of $(2)$ in $H^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$.

> Are we able to show $v\in H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$ and $(3)$? If so, *how*?

If this is not possible without further assumptions on $\Lambda$ or $\partial\Lambda$: Where can I find a proof of the existence of such a $v$ (which is not necessarily the special $v$ constructed above) in the case where $\Lambda$ is a [polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron)?

Comment: Let me note that I'm aware of [this result for a polygon ($d=2$)](http://www.esaim-m2an.org/articles/m2an/pdf/1985/01/m2an1985190101111.pdf).